# Can I force a LOAD DATA LOCAL statement to abort if an error is not loaded?

Tags: mysql, csv, error-handling

I am trying to load a CSV file into a MySQL table with the `load data local` statement. After loading it, the statement reports

```
Query OK, 1030 rows affected, 7314 warnings (0.03 sec)
Records: 1043  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 13  Warnings: 7314
```

Fur my purposes, skipping 13 records is not OK - I'd rather have the statement to fail with an error message.

As the `load data local` statement is found in an `.sql` file that I execute from a batch file, I'd also appreciate if there was a possibility to abort the execution of the batch file on the first error.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Show real query text. Does it includes `LINES STARTING BY`?

Comment: From the docs (emphasis added), "If you do not specify either modifier, the behavior depends on whether the LOCAL modifier is specified. Without LOCAL, **an error occurs when a duplicate key value is found, and the rest of the text file is ignored.** With LOCAL, the default behavior is the same as if IGNORE is specified; this is because the server has no way to stop transmission of the file in the middle of the operation."

Comment: Ok, I understand that the server cannot stop the transmission. But as far as I can see from the docu, there is no way to have a warning signalled as error (with LOCAL).